# How to filter List Inside List using Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a View Model

```
public class TechnicianZipInformation
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public virtual Technician Technician { get; set; }
    }
```

Inside this view Model the data Type of Technician is Technician Class

```
public class Technician 
{
  public int Id {get; set}
  public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; } // Inside work order there is another member id of int.
}
```

Let's say stepOne is the List of TechnicalZipInformation.
Now I need to filter the list of work order whose id !=52 inside Technician inside List of TechnicianZipInformation.How Can I do this?

I tried by following

```
var testResult = stepOne.Select(x => x).Where( z=> z.Technician.WorkOrders.Select(x => x.Id != 52)).ToList();
```

It didn't help how can i do this?

image example :-
[image]

Comment: Try `var testResult = stepOne.Where(z => z.Technician.WorkOrders.Any(x => x.Id != 52)).ToList();`. Remove `Select(x => x)` and use `Any` instead of `Select` inside `Where`.

Comment: @Karan It's actually ICollection<TechnicianZipInformation> so it couldn't take ForEach

Comment: @Karan using foreach i am getting an error cannot assigned void to an implicity typed variable.What might be the reason?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651530/retain-parent-instance-if-using-selectmany-on-nested-collection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) Linq function to make a single list of `WorkOrders` across all `TechnicalZipInformations`.

```
List<WorkOrder> result = stepOne.SelectMany(t => t.Technician.WorkOrders.Where(x => x.Id != 52)).ToList();
```

Comment: I need a result in ICollection<TechnicalZipInformation> not int List<Workorder>

Answer (score 0):

To remove `WorkOrders` with `Id = 52` you can use use `ToList()` proceed with `ForEach` and reassign `WorkOrders` with `Where` like below query.

```
stepOne.ToList()
.ForEach(z => z.Technician.WorkOrders = z.Technician.WorkOrders.Where(x => x.Id != 52).ToList());
```

- To use `ForEach`, convert your `ICollection` to `List` with `ToList()`.
- Filter `WorkOrders` with `z.Technician.WorkOrders.Where(x => x.Id != 52).ToList()`
- Reassign `z.Technician.WorkOrders` with above filter as `.ForEach(z => z.Technician.WorkOrders = z.Technician.WorkOrders.Where(x => x.Id != 52).ToList())`.